# How to use the Photobucket REST API?

Tags: api, oauth, photobucket

Has anyone successfully used the Photobucket REST API? According to the pathetic [docs](http://pic.pbsrc.com/dev_help/PB_Developer_API_Guide.pdf), it requires OAuth authorization, which would require a consumer key *and* secret, but registering an app gives you but a single developer key, which I have no idea what to do with.

Answer (score 1):

If you go into photobucket and go to your application and view the details, you will see there is a developer key and what they call a 'private' key. I would assume this is the secret you are looking for. If you manage to make a successful call to the photobucket API, I would appreciate if you could provide the URL you used (anonymize anything private like the signature, of course)